# Swift UITextField Constraint - Add Textfield in Middle of the View

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uitextfield

I want to add a UITextField to my View programatically.
The distance from left and from right should be 20.
The distance from top should be 100.

if i add constraint in the designer it works:
-> in Simulator it looks like that: [image: simulator]

My code now:

```
let EmailTextfield = UITextField()
override func loadView() {        
    super.loadView()

    EmailTextfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    EmailTextfield.layer.borderWidth = 2
    EmailTextfield.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

    EmailTextfield.addConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: EmailTextfield,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: nil,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 40
    ))

    //left
    self.view.addConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: EmailTextfield,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 20
    ))

    //right
    self.view.addConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: EmailTextfield,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 20
    ))

    //top
    self.view.addConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: EmailTextfield,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 100
    ))
)
```

When i run my code:
[image: UITextField programatically]

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing constant must be the negative value -20 instead of 20.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the RIGHT constraints constant from 20 to -20. or you can switch the RIGHT constraints items (item: self.view, toItem: EmailTextfield) and leave the constant being 20.

Comment: i said right cause that is how he commented the constraint in code... ;)